# Camel Springboot microservice deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-camel

How do you deploy new routes into an already deployed camel springboot microservice?

Lets say, I create a microservice getData and deploy it into Kubernetes in some Pod

Tomorrow, I want to add another microservice called getInfo to another Kubernetes

next, I edit make changes to getData, and update the project.

Now, do I do all this into a separate spring project or I can use 1 project and deploy them into different Kubernetes?

Need help to understand the deployment